Excel XLOOKUP with Wildcards - Functionality Change
I'm playing with XLOOKUP with wildcards (Match_Mode 2). I believe it used to be if you want it to return results where a item in that excel it was = =XLOOKUP(""&"Text"&"",A:A,B:B,0,2), if it was only before =XLOOKUP("Text"&"*",A:A,B:B,0,2).
I'm finding now you can't get just before nor just after and you don't need "*"& just the star. =XLOOKUP("text*",A:A,B:B,0,2) The last comment is shown in red in the image.
Please take a look at the image below and provide thoughts

Thanks, Brad
Thought this might help.


If you are hardcoding the word within quotes, then "Beyond*" or "*Beyond*" or "*Beyond" as per your needs but if you are not then you will need to use in this way --> "*"&D1&"*" or "*"&D1 or D1&"*" as per your requirements. But what is your question, what are you trying to accomplish ? is it only the use of * wildcard operator within quotes while using the word hardcoded? Also using XLOOKUP() will return only the first occurrence while for multiple records you will need FILTER() function, I know you are aware of this still --> =FILTER(B4:B6,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D1,A4:A6)))

Thanks for reaching back out so quickly. I realize it would only return the first result. The formulas in the screen caps are =formulatext. What suggesting it I was expecting that I needed ""&D1&"" or ""&D1 as you suggest but it allow works "Beyond" or "*Beyond" which I wasn't expecting. Wondered if something changed.

This is not going to work: =XLOOKUP(""&D1&"",A4:A6,B4:B6,,2) it will return an #N/A error. You will need the wildcard operator. =XLOOKUP(D1&"*",A4:A6,B4:B6,,2). May be i am not understanding your requirements clearly or i am missing something.

What I was trying to say, you cant use empty strings concatenated with lookup value and use matchmode for wildcard character. it won't work you need to supply one of the wildcard character operators as per your needs. it can be * or ? or ~

@BradR please surround your "code" in back ticks so the*` does not italicize the text.

Sorry I don't know what's happening with my posting, what I'm trying to say and show with the screen cap. =XLOOKUP(""&"Beyond"&"",A:A,B:B,0,2) returns the same result as =XLOOKUP("Beyond*",A:A,B:B,0,2). It seems like the "*"& can just be a * now.

It keeps dropping the s when i past the formula =XLOOKUP(""&"Beyond"&"*",A:A,B:B,0,2) is what I'm using

@BradR you have to put backticks ( ) in front and end of your formula or the*` will make the text italicized.

so the formula is =XLOOKUP('""&"Beyond"&'"", A:A,B:B,0,2) see if that works I tried using the '

Ah I understood now what you are trying to say. =XLOOKUP(D1&"*",A4:A6,B4:B6,,2) this will return one but this will return two =XLOOKUP("*"&D1,A4:A6,B4:B6,,2) change the value to understand. XLOOKUP() with wildcard before and after is working accordingly as per MSFT Documentation

Sorry I just can't get to work nor can I paste an image of the formula in the comment.

Quick way to put it.  If you look at the screen cap the formula in D19 (shown in E19) returns the same value as the one in D6 (shown E6) it seems the & etc are no longer needed.

Instead of 1 change those numbers to 2,3,4 etc and see the difference. when you are using "*"&D1&"*" it is returning the first occurrence and now change the value in B6 to 2 to see the difference in usage of before and after wildcard operator --> after --> D1&"*" and before --> "*"&D1

Added an image. Thought that might point out the only real question.

I dont see anything wrong in the behavior of the usages. Also you are not reading comments i think so. * means any number of strings.

And the * can come both before  or after the word.

Thanks everyone for your help. I have what I need figuredout.
